# Regex for default AWS private hostnames

Tags: regex, linux, bash, amazon-web-services, shell

Our AWS default hostnames are "`ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx`", example "`ip-10-96-2-123`", I am writing a simple shell script (bash) to detect if `/etc/hostname` contains that or something else and if it does contains the default hostname then run the change hostname script, I got everything down but I am pretty terrible at writing an efficient regex, which is why I am seeking help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this I guess:

`ip(-[0-9]{1,3}){4}`

it will match the "ip" string and then 4 groups of a dash and 1-3 numbers